# Unexpected error "packet is too large", closing connection socketio flask

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

After new update of python-engineio am receiving, "**Unexpected error "packet is too large", closing connection** socketio flask" in the **python-engineio logs**, when I try to send large amount of data.

It was working fine few days ago.

For server am using : flask_socketio
For client am using : python_socketio[client]

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a security related change, to prevent DoS attacks. Set the `max_http_buffer_size` argument in your `SocketIO` constructor to your desired maximum size. The default is 1MB, same as the reference JavaScript implementation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Got your point.